# Store erlang socket to database

Tags: database, sockets, erlang, gen-tcp

I need to store sockets into database,
gen_tcp:accept returns something like

```
#Port<0.5>
```

I can convert it to a bitstring using io_lib:format

```
["Port<0.5>"]
```

to store it into database but how do i convert it back to its original state to use it to send and receive data?

**Update:**
I tried `term_to_binary` but mysql-otp failed to insert it so i did `binary_to_list(term_to_binary(Socket))` , it inserted fine but adds extra <<194,xxx,xx...>> at the start of the binary into the database, any solutions? Why is it happening? If it doesn't add extra data i can convert it back fine using `binary_to_term`.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Erlang! I think you are going against the flow. Wanting to store a socket handle into a db seems a "design smell". Embrace Erlang, instead of trying to adapt Erlang to how you would do something in another language :-)

Comment: Its a chat server and i need to store online users sockets, storing big list of sockets in a variable isn't a good idea, is it? I was concerned about it but unfortunately asking these questions on stack overflow results in down votes for being too broad and ban from posting future questions.

Comment: Is dictionary gonna handle thousands of sockets fine enough?

Comment: I see the concern about using a list, sure, it would not be a good approach in this case. You could use for example ETS, which is built-in and doesn't need any conversion. But for this kind of questions, I suggest asking on the Erlang mailing list or Slack channel.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and suggestions i really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed varchar to varbinary and now i can directly insert `term_to_binary` into database and then reuse it using `binary_to_term`.